Url CI page not found
$routes->get('/','Home::index');

URL "http://localhost/" it's work fine but
$routes->get('a','Home::index');

URL "http://localhost/a" it's return Page Not Found. Whats wrong?
I try to make new project and i meet same problem.
I'm sory for my bad english.

Please ask your question in English.

Ok thank @Marleen im sory i can't for english languange

is it resolve? Please share Home Controller

I only change the Routes.php, i think the Controller work fine no error my Home Controller is default from CI.
